# webpack built 0 bytes

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I am just learning how to use webpack. Here is my situation. So, in my Django project, I have a static folder. Django has to know about the static files, so I have made an index.js file there. The file looks like this:

```
// index.js
import { pickRandomColor } './dashboard.js'
document.body.style.backgroundColor = pickRandomColor();
```

My dashboard.js inside the static folder has all the js code for my dashboard. I'm just trying to bring in some code and build it using webpack to test. My package.json resides in the root directory of the django project:

```
- root
-- static
---  dashboard.js
- package.json
```

My package.json has the following:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"build_dashboard": "webpack static/js/index.js main.js"
 },
...
"devDependencies": {
"eslint": "^6.8.0",
"webpack": "^4.44.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
},
```

Now, when I run

```
npm run build_dashboard
```

I get:

```
Hash: 01134d33832ec1eee2c0
Version: webpack 4.44.1
Time: 482ms
Built at: 08/11/2020 4:58:19 PM
  Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  983 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] multi ./static/js/index.js ./main.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./static/js/index.js 0 bytes {0} [built]
[2] ./main.js 0 bytes {0} [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
```

Why can't npm build it and why is it building 0 bytes? How can I fix this?

Comment: Change "build_dashboard": "webpack static/js/index.js main.js" to "build_dashboard": "webpack static/js/index.js main.js --mode development"

Comment: It gives me `ERROR in multi ./static/js/index.js ./main.js ./development/`. I also tried `"build_dashboard": "webpack static/js/index.js main.js --mode=development"` and still getting an error. This time the error is: `ERROR in ./static/js/index.js 1:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:27)` In both cases, I still get the warning: `WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set`

Comment: try npm run build_dashboard --mode=development. You might also want to see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

Answer (score 0):

You've got an `Unexpected token` error. Try to replace:

```js
import { pickRandomColor } './dashboard.js'
```

by:

```js
import { pickRandomColor } from './dashboard.js'
```

Comment: That is a good point. I did change it, but it did not resolve the problem. It still gives me `[0] multi ./static/js/index.js ./main.js 40 bytes {0} [built]  [1] ./main.js 0 bytes {0} [built] [2] ./static/js/index.js + 1 modules 65.2 KiB {0} [built]    | ./static/js/index.js 110 bytes [built]    | ./static/js/dashboard.js 65.1 KiB [built]` I also get the warning `The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.` How do I set the mode? where is the config file?

Comment: Where is your `index.js`? What is there in your main.js? What's your Webpack config? I'd need more infos.

Comment: index.js is in the static folder (`root/static/js/index.js`), main.js is in the root folder (`root`). I do not know where to look for the Webpack config file